# How to apply 2 different conditions in the filter of list?

Tags: list, filter

I have two different conditions based on which I need to apply filter on the list data.

The conditions are based on the user role and status column.

I have applied the filter condition as :
Createdby equals to [Me] or Manager equals [Me] and Status equals to "Resubmitted" or Status equals to "In Progress".

The condition never turns out to be true so I none of my forms are visible.

Please guide...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In addition you need to accurately describe the condition you're after. What you've written could be (A or B) and (C or D) or it could be A or (B and C) or D or lots of other combinations. You won't get anywhere without being very specific in your details.

Answer (score 6):

To group conditions like this,(I'm going to assume (A or B) and (C or D)) you could use calculated columns in conjunction with you list view filter.

Create two columns like this:

1stLogic = OR(CreatedBy = A, Manager = B)
2ndLogic = OR(Status = C, Status = D)

List view filters: 1stLogic equals Yes AND 2ndLogic = Yes

I haven't tried using the current user as data, or the [Me] operator, so that may be a problem with this method.

Comment: +1 for creative problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint UI does not allow you to group the ORs and ANDs when building the filter in the browser. Thus the order of operations is top down.

To group the operations in your filter you would need to customize the view in ShaerPoint Designer.

More specific instuctions can be found [here.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/filter-data-in-a-data-view-HA010103041.aspx#BM3)

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to filter by multiple conditions in a SharePoint list when the logic combination would need parenthesis to force the evaluation sequence.

You can try the third-part add-ons, such as [BoostSolutions List Advanced Filter](http://www.boostsolutions.com/sharepoint-list-advanced-filter.html), [Kwizcom List Filter Plus](http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-list-filter-plus/overview/), and more.